# Integral of exponential combined with sine function

Tags: integration

$\int e^{a\sin^2(bx)} \sin^2(bx) dx$

I have tried changing of variables and integration by part. But I could not achieve the analytical solution. I would like to have an analytical solution rather than the numerical solution. I would appreciate in advance any guidelines.

Comment: I doubt that this integral has a closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: How did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't given as a definite integral? Because there are a few of those that would have closed form. Otherwise, with $u = \cos(2bx)$, you can get the somewhat simpler $-e^{a/2}/(4b)\int e^{-au/2}\sqrt{(1-u)/(1+u)}du$, but I doubt you can do any better even in terms of special functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int e^{a\,\sin^2(bx)} \sin^2(bx)\, dx$$

Let
$$\sin^2(bx)=t \implies x=\frac{\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}{b} \implies dx=\frac{1}{2 b \sqrt{1-t} \sqrt{t}}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2 b}\int \frac{\sqrt{t} }{\sqrt{1-t}}\,e^{a t}\,dt$$ Now, use
$$ \frac{\sqrt{t} }{\sqrt{1-t}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} t^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$ and
$$J_n=\int t^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,e^{a t}\,dt=a^{-n-\frac{3}{2}}\int  y^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,e^y\,dy$$ to face incomplete gamma functions.